# Status Bar returns when UIImagePickerViewController is called?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

Everything in my app is working a treat - but there is one niggling problem.

The UIImagePickerController seems to return the status bar when it is called. Obviously the app has the statusbar hidden throughout.

Now I have worked around this by rehiding it upon completion or canelation of the picker. This resulted in a black bar at the top of the app. So after the rehide I have had to reposition the titlebar and other table contents for it to fit.

All in all this works perfectly fine. However, the UIImagePickerController is called in detail view of a table. Therefore when the user has used the picker (and ive resized after use) and clicks the back button to return to the main table there is a small graphical glitch.

The detail view has been shifted up to hide the statusbar void, yet when I return to the main table and the app slides horizontally back to the main view, for a split second a 20px black box can be seen above the items on the detail view?

To recap. UIImagePickerController returns the staus bar (seemingly no matter what) and after coding to get rid and reformat the view I get a time (messy) graphical issue when returning to the main view.

Surely there is a way to stop the statusbar returning so I dont have to bodge bar back out using code? I have it set 'off' in the plist.

It very odd! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This helps to me.

1) You must delegate the UIImagePickerController

2) Add this to ViewController:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{    // Esconder el StatusBar. Provocado por el iOS7 y el UIImagePickerController
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

implementing UIimagepicker controller use this.and hide status bar in to plist(statusbar initialy hidden=true) and set Uiview size 320x480 & implementing this

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
```